# Изменение прав на php

Tags: php

Есть ссылка, "Личный кабинет". При нажатии на неё нас кидает к форме авторизации. Существует так же `$_SESSION['logged_user']`, сессия которая обозначает "авторизованность" пользователя.

Нужно чтобы людей, у которых `isset($_SESSION['logged_user']` кидало уже в Личный Кабинет, а не к форме логина. Вот код:

```
<a href="login.php">Личный Кабинет</a>
```

Пытался сделать что-то наподобие этого, не вышло (ибо не совсем допер куда вставлять или как правильно обратиться к ссылке):

```
<?php 
        if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
            header('Location: user.php');
        }
        else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }

    ?>
```

Может как-то можно через jQuery значение атрибута поменять? Как применить к этому php и вообще в целом организовать? Помогите)

Comment: Добавлю, user.php это страница Личного кабинета

Comment: Не нужно редиректить людей на сервер, если они уже на сервере. Что-то вроде `include('user.php');` сделает то же самое без редиректа.

Answer (score 0):

Всё что связано с привелегиями и доступами осуществляйте на стороне серверра т.к. всё что вы сделаете на JS можно будет обойти используя один только девтулз.

Комментарии даны верные, не используйте редиректы, используйте подключение файлов по ситуации, то есть делайте вывод по условию, так вы не будете создавать лишнюю нагрузку на сервер из-за многократных обращений.

```
<?php 
    if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
        require_once('user.php');
    }
    else {
        require_once('login.php');
    }

?>
```

Comment: А как мне ваш код применить к ссылке? К тэгу <a>

Comment: Этот код вставьте в файл lk.php и измените href в самой ссылке

Comment: Не работает, нажимаю на ссылку, скидывает на lk.php, с формой для входа, хотя сессия logged_user активна

Comment: Это значит что перменная logged_user существует в сессии, т.к. даёт true при проверке на сущетствование isset($_SESSION['logged_user']).
Напишите вначале скрипта var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user']); чтобы увидеть что хранится в этой переменной в данный момент